# Will non-block design such as Async/await block the Node in multiple requests and CPU-bound situation

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am a newbie to Node.js, and meet a problem to design non-block codes for node.js.
The first choose is async/await, such as following:

```
router.post('/handleFiles', async(req, res) => {
        // .....
        try {
            let sqr1 = "INSERT INTO ........;"
            await new Promise((res, rej) => {
                pool.query(sqr1, (err, row) => {
                    if (err) return rej(err);
                    ...do something...
                });
            });
            let sqr2 = "UPDATE .....;"
            await new Promise((res, rej) => {
                pool.query(sqr2, (err, row) => {
                    if (err) return rej(err);
                    ...do another...
                });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    });
```

What if the sql need 20 secs to finish its job and then, do some other file operations and calculation, in this case, will the node block other requests? There seems other choose to do CPU-bounded work, such as child_process, it will
goes in another way, such as

```
var fork = require('child_process').fork;
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var worker = fork('./SQL.js');
    worker.on('message', function (m) {
         res.send(m.result.toString()); 
        })
    });
    
    worker.send({type:'insert', num:--req.query.n||10});
});
```

What is the good design for node.js to do a heavy loading job for a request,
and concurrency to meet another request?
Any instruction is highly appreciated, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check on how [Node.js event loop](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick) works first. The beauty of Node.js is in its event driven pattern without the need of multi-thread*. Basically, even if the SQL takes 20 seconds to complete, the request is current outside of the process, it is processed by the SQL server and is handled by the network layer / another process / container / service. (Thanks to libuv)

Within that 20 seconds where the request is still in the other layers, Node.js can still process other requests or perform CPU-bound tasks until the result is returned from the SQL server.

In other words, unlike Go or Python, Node.js event based system makes it such that everytime you call for `await`, if the Promise hasn't returned, Node.js will "jump"* to another statement that are pending to be processed instead of stuck for 20 seconds without receiving any requests.

* A lot of explanations above are very simplified to hide the complex details

Comment: I see some codes using promise to replace the for loop use case; it seems a very different design when comparing to ASP C# MVC. To meet Node.js concurrence design, is there possible a template to follow and use regardless the difference between DB query and for loop calculations, thanks.